# Can/Should Teams replace all (internal) documentation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm evaluating the new teams feature.  I really like the idea, but before I dump too much time into populating it with questions I want to know if it can (should) replace all (internal) documentation.  I'm curious what everyone thinks.

I know one of the sample questions says "No matter what you ask, remember that **the best questions are clear and specific.**", so a question like "What is the URL for the management console" would work.  But what about something like "What are the IP addresses of all our servers?".

I realize this is a terribly written question, but I'm just having trouble justifying putting *some* (internal) documentation here if I can't put it *all* here.

---

So how is everyone using Teams? Do you still maintain other (internal) documentation?  How do you differentiate the two?

Comment: Wow, that was the fastest downvote ever. There is literally no way anyone even read it

Comment: Yes, you said "all documentation"

Comment: Updated title to clarify implied context.

Comment: Can: yes. Should: likely no. Teams is not a documentation suite, but a Q&A site, and there are several solutions that will likely work better.

Comment: Thanks Erik. We were using Confluence, which I liked, but we just switched to Office 365.  I'm not a fan of Sharepoint, so I'm weighing my options.  I'd love to hear more detail about your thoughts in an answer if you have time.

Comment: Meh, that would be more on topic in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), since then I would go recommending software. Also, my organization currently uses a software solution that's only available in my country for most documentation, and GitLab for some technical documentation, but that works best if you use GitLab for DevOps too.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not Teams replaces all of your company's internal documentation is a decision left to your company.  Like any other tool out there, having an entire organization commit to it for every purpose is really up to that organization and whether or not they're comfortable with it.

Suffice to say, you'll get no comfort from strangers outside of your organization telling you whether or not you should go all in.  You should evaluate it like *every* tool you evaluate and determine if it's the best fit for you.

Comment: Part of evaluating a tool is researching how other people use it.  This is me doing that part. :)

Comment: Most evaluation committees I've been on haven't focused on how others are using a particular tool.  It's chiefly been about what value we've been able to glean out of it and how we're capable of maximizing it. Seeing how others have used a tool has led to "best practices" thinking and us putting our brains on autopilot, which is very much not the goal.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I'm a committee of one.  And another perspective is never a bad thing.